# How do I create a column in a method chain and use it to fillna another column without using pipe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.24.2.

Within a method chain, I want to create a new column (say with `assign`) and fill `na` values in another column using the new column, without using the `pipe` function. Is this possible?

An example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, 11, 12], "b": [21, np.nan, 25]}).assign(
    c=lambda x: x["a"] / 2
)
```

Now let's say I want to fill the `na` value in `b` with the value of `c`, adding onto the method chain. Unlike `assign`, `fillna` doesn't evaluate callables. This fills in the value with the lambda itself instead of evaluating it.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, 11, 12], "b": [21, np.nan, 25]})
    .assign(c=lambda x: x["a"] / 2)
    .fillna({"b": lambda x: x["c"]})
)
```

and this raises a `KeyError` as expected:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, 11, 12], "b": [21, np.nan, 25]})
    .assign(c=lambda x: x["a"] / 2)
    .fillna({"b": df["c"]})
)
```

I could do define a function for this and use pipe:

```py
import pandas as pd


def chain_fillna(df, na_column, fill_column):
    return df.fillna({na_column: df[fill_column]})

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, 11, 12], "b": [21, np.nan, 25]})
    .assign(c=lambda x: x["a"] / 2)
    .pipe(chain_fillna, "b", "c")
)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use pipe?

Comment: Pipe is fine. I guess I'm skirting the rules of SO a bit by phrasing my question the way I did. I didn't want to write "what is 'the' pythonic/pandorable way to do this". I can always use pipe for any data frame munging. I think the answer from ALollz using assign "feels" more correct than using pipe.

Comment: But is there any necessity to have all of these arguments chained? For certain things it can be nice, but for others, it's nice to just assign a variable so you don't need all of these lambdas thrown around.

Comment: Nope. Not necessary. I'm only asking because Tom Augspurger described methid chaining in his modern pandas series (now three years old!), and I've been playing around with chaining function calls for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just again with `assign` calling `.fillna()`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 11, 12], 'b': [21, np.nan, 25]})
          .assign(c=lambda x: x['a'] / 2)
          .assign(b=lambda x: x.b.fillna(x.c))
      )
#    a     b    c
#0  10  21.0  5.0
#1  11   5.5  5.5
#2  12  25.0  6.0
```

Comment: How can I pass `c` as some string? i.e. let say `Name = 'c'` and I want to pass `Name` as the name of new column